# Kendo Upload in Grid Popup Editor: How to prevent window close when upload throw exception

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I do not know if this is a strange case, but I can hardly find similar situation on the web.

What I've got is a Kendo Upload Control (async upload multiple files), in a Kendo Grid Popup Editor Template.

I am trying to implement the follow behavior:

- User may select multiple files from the upload control, but not yet upload.
- When user clicks on the default "update" button of the popup window, triggers the upload control's async upload action.
- If user clicks on "cancel" button or closes the window, without clicking "update", the window is closed and the selected files are not uploaded.
- When all files are uploaded successfully, the popup window is closed and the grid gets refreshed.

I have already implemented the above functionality without any problem (Even though, I have to intercept many Kendo Control's javascript).

**My problem is the following:**

- If the total file size (in DB + pending one) is bigger than a certain amount, then as a server validation, I throw an exception from server, **no files are uploaded**, and the **popup window should not be closed,** while an error message will display on the popup window.
- If user gets to the above point and selects other files, the previous selected pending files will be cleared and will behave just like a brand new cycle.
- If user gets to the above point and clicks the "cancel" button or clicks the "X" icon, the window should be closed.

I can find no easy way to implement this.

What I was able to find related to this was [Upload in Grid Popup editor](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/upload-in-grid-popup-editor).

But, it still does not show how I can catch my own Exception in front-end, stop the window from closing, and display the error message.

Please provide any advice! Thanks!

Comment: Post your code. You wouldn't have had to explain all this if you had just posted some code.

Answer (score 0):

How about preventing event propogation in the onUpload event and have your window `OnClose` event check if it is all clear to close based of some flag indicating safe to close.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload().HtmlAttributes(new { Style = "width:300px;" })
    .Name("upImport")
    .Messages(e => e.DropFilesHere("Drop files here").Select("Select file"))
    .Multiple(false)            
    .Async(a => a
        .Save("UploadFile", "File")
        .Remove("RemoveFile", "File")
        .AutoUpload(true)
        .SaveField("files")
    )    
    .Events(events => events
        .Error("onError")
        .Success("onSuccess")
        .Upload("onUpload")
    )
)

<script type="text/javascript">

var _canPost=true;

function onUpload(e) {
    _canPost=true; 
    var files = e.files;
    $.each(files, function () {
        if (this.size / 1024 / 1024 > 5) {
            alert("Max 5Mb file size is allowed!");
            e.preventDefault();
            //Block window from closing flag here 
            _canPost=false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However it won't work, as 1.) onUpload fire per file upload (5 files, 5 different requests)  2.) I have to check those files already in DB as well, which must through server side 3.) I tried preventDefault() for the popup window onclose but it was not working as the window closing is caused by the grid rebind event.

Comment: Could you send something back in the onUpload that would indicate to the client the current state of affairs with the uploads on the server? Since you are storing them in the db anyway, this should be possible.

Comment: yes I did something similar to this: I calculate the total pending file size, and send along back to server for the first file uploaded, then at server side I add them to DB file size to verify the constrain, and if fail, I throw exception. And here is the point that I stuck: the window will close anyway even if I throw exception.

Comment: Is the exception coming back in the Error event handler of the Upload control?